# how to change textview when flip the viewflipper using only one kind of layout

Tags: android, viewflipper

I want to dynamically change the text in textview when flip the views. problem is that all the views use the same layout so when setText the android crashed. Any suggestion?

```
    if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()){
        Log.d(TAG,"viewflipper left starting");
        vf_route_stop.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_out));
        vf_route_stop.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_in));
        Log.d(TAG,"viewflipper left before setText");

        vf_route_stop.showNext();
        tvbutton.setText("left");
        Log.d(TAG,"viewflipper left ending");
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same layout shouldn't be a problem.  I'd look to where you populate the ViewGroup with Views.

Comment: i did not use ViewGroup. actually how to use it??

Comment: ViewFlipper is a subclass of ViewGroup.